# Is there a hostname property in container object of Arquillian Cube?

Tags: java, docker, cube, jboss-arquillian, hostname

I'm trying to set a hostname of my Arquillian Cube container object just as in docker-compose file. Is it possible to do this using some Java annotation?

This is a simple LDAP container which I'm going to use for Spring application testing purposes. I'm basically trying to avoid using docker-compose file.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Arquillian docs](http://arquillian.org/arquillian-cube/#_networks):

> 6.1. Networks
>
> You can define networks using cube format (Docker Compose v1 (the one
>   supported by Cube) does not have support to networks. For defining
>   them you only need to use the reserved word networks.

`src/test/resources/cube`:

```java
networks: //(1)
   mynetwork: //(2) 
       driver: bridge //(3) 
tomcat:
  image: tutum/tomcat:7.0
  exposedPorts: [8089/tcp]
  networkMode: mynetwork // (4)
```

> 1. Reserved word to indicate start of network definition
> 2. Network name
> 3. Driver used. Currently this is the only supported property due not support in docker-java
> 4. Sets the network where container must join.

This is the alternative to using the Docker-Compose Format.

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: I actually meant using Container-Object format so that I could specify the hostname using Java annotation in my @Cube object class.